# How do I append the string with the given input while inserting into db using laravel migration?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

**This is what I am tried?**

```
$temp->Pid="GC"+$form1->input('Pid');
```

Comment: In PHP `.` is used to concatenate, not `+`.

Comment: or you can use string interpolation `"GC{$form1->input('Pid')}"`

Comment: Yes..ThankYou So much Sir!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think update your code like :

$temp->Pid= "GC" . $form1->input('Pid');

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use . To signify a concatenation. For instance:

```
$fullname = $firstname . $lastname;
```

Assuming they are both strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery/javascript syntax to concatenate the string(eg. + operator). So you need to use php syntax. So the could would be

$Pid = $form1->input('Pid');
$temp->Pid = "GC".$Pid;